# how do I fix this npm install error? Failing after Windows 11 update

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm

I just installed Windows 11 with Visual Studio 2022, and when installing an app that was working fine on Windows 10 I am running into all these errors in the npm install portion. The app is the UI for a website written in react. Initially I was getting errors about python not being installed, so I installed that and modified the path (and added python2.exe) and fixed that issue. Regarding the missing Visual Studio 2017 error, I made sure to select "desktop development" in the Visual Studio install which is supposed to include the build tools.  I'm still getting these errors though, any ideas? Here is the log:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=  
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 C:\Python27\python2.EXE
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python2.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.17.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.17.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.17.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
npm ERR! gyp verb Not using VS2017: No usable installation of VS2017 found
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:30136) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python2.EXE
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\tomrh\\.node-gyp\\18.17.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\tomrh\\.node-gyp\\18.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\tomrh\\.node-gyp\\18.17.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     options.duplicate_basename_check)
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 130, in Load
npm ERR!     params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 2783, in Load
npm ERR!     variables, includes, depth, check, True)
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 399, in LoadTargetBuildFile
npm ERR!     includes, True, check)
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 271, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     aux_data, includes, check)
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 308, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict
npm ERR!     LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check),
npm ERR!   File "D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 251, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     None)
npm ERR!   File "C:\Users\tomrh\.node-gyp\18.17.0\include\node\common.gypi", line 1
npm ERR!     e_data_file_flag%': 1
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Projects\\oprcfda\\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\oprcfda\opr-cfda-website-main-ui\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had node v18.17.0 and it did not work.

I downgraded to 14.21.3 (courtesy of [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)) because that's the version my colleague is successfully using.

It works!

My error looked to be the same as yours.

```
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     options.duplicate_basename_check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 130, in Load
npm ERR!     params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2783, in Load
npm ERR!     variables, includes, depth, check, True)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 399, in LoadTargetBuildFile
npm ERR!     includes, True, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 271, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     aux_data, includes, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 308, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict
npm ERR!     LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check),
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 251, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     None)
npm ERR!   File "/home/shaun/.node-gyp/18.17.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1
npm ERR!     e_data_file_flag%': 1
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-104-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/shaun/repos/ink/SPA-Gallery/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I was using a newer version of node and npm that was incompatible with this older project. Reverting to an older version solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'd love to know which versions of node and npm you downgraded to.